# Spotify song change notification crashes pantheon

Tags: pantheon, crash, spotify

Whenever I play spotify, song change notifications cause my whole display to blank, and then come back in a way that looks like pantheon crashing. If I'm playing an album with some shorter tracks and two notifications come relatively close together pantheon crashes entirely and my only option is a hard reboot.

Has anyone had this problem before, is there anything I can do about this? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling spotify, but that didn't work. I'm using the official deb.

Comment: For some reason, on my machine Spotify doesn't show any notifications. There's no dedicated 'Spotify' setting in `System Settings > Notifications` though. `Other` setting is set to show bubbles only.

Comment: For me, the setting is within the spotify app. I, of course, just have them disabled for now. But I'd like to reenable them if I knew a way to avoid this issue.

Comment: BTW, where exactly is this Notification setting within Spotify app? Tried to find it, but couldn't...

Comment: Settings > Display Options > Show desktop notifications when song changes

Comment: Turned them on, tried to recreate this issue. Turns out, on my system Spotify's notification never appear stacked. They are displayed one at a time, one after the other. If two tracks are super-short (say, 1 sec each), the notification for the second one is displayed in the same spot as the first one - as if replacing the first one in a sliding manner. So they never clash. I installed Spotify from their webpage, not from eOs AppStore.